# How to check how many rows is in table using SOCI and C++?

Tags: c++, soci

Simple question. I have a table Person. I have in it two rows:

```
1 Joe Doe joe.doe@ymail.com
2 Vivien Doe v.doe@gmail.com
```

How to write a SOCI statement, which will tell me (return) how many rows I have in my table? (Here, in my example, I have 2 rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of rows in an SQL table use the `count(*)` function like this:

```
select count(*) from Person
```

To be more specific - to get the number into C++ variable use:

```
int count;
sql << "select count(*) from person", into(count);
```

Comment: I thought that theres some kind of soci-way. But thanks, I will use it - simple and nice!:)

Comment: Keep in mind though, that doing this for a large table is expensive.

Comment: @aleguna: Could you suggest a better solution? Is there any?

Comment: @aleguna: No, it does not have to be always expensive. It depends on the SQL server/service. It may very well be `O(1)` and it likely is for a single table with no `where` clause.